# How can I see the assets deployed on Statemint/Statemine with all their related information on Polkadot.js UI?

Tags: polkadot-js, assets, statemine, statemint

How can I see the assets deployed on Statemint or Statemine parachains and read all their parameters and metadata? I would like to do that directly on Polkadot.js UI, is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Once you are in the Polkadot.js/apps UI, connect to **Statemint** network (Polkadot ecosystem), click on *Network* tab and then on *Assets* to see the complete list of deployed assets listed by *asset ID*. Follow the same process to see the existing assets on **Statemine** for Kusama ecosystem.

Moreover, in the Polkadot.js/apps UI, if you go to *Developer* tab, and click on *Chain State* you can query the state of the chain for [the **assets pallet**](https://docs.rs/pallet-assets/latest/pallet_assets/) to see the entire set of parameters and metadata for each asset (by asset ID) with *asset* and *metadata* state queries respectively. In the screenshot below you can see all this information shown for the asset ID 21, wBTC.

[image]